# What blogging software is used for omgiv.com?

Tags: blog

Does anyone know what blogging software they used for omgiv.com?  I like the style and would like to use the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the source will show it is WordPress 3.1

Comment: To add to what John said, the theme is called "Delicous Magazine" and seems to be available on a number of websites offering Wordpress themes.